# How to display error message in a jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
if(emailVal == '') {
              $("#email").after('<span class="error"><font color="red">Please enter your email address.</span>');
              hasError = true;
          }
```

when i use above javascript, message displays besides `email textbox`

```
<form:input path="email"  id="email"/>
             <c:if test="${!empty is_exist_user}">
             <span class="error"><font color="red">${is_exist_user}</font></span>               
            </c:if>
```

but when i use above code in jsp file, message displays below `email textbox`, how can i get this textbox besides `email textbox`

Comment: Wow, a `<font>`. This element is deprecated since HTML4 in 1998. Why don't you just declare `color: red;` in the CSS `.error` class which you're using there in the `<span>`?

Answer (score 0):

Either use CSS to tweak whatever is produced by whatever custom tag that is, modify the html produced by that custom tag, or don't use the custom tag.

Comment: which custom tag u r talking about

Comment: @Romi ... The only custom tag in your snippet, `<form:input>`.

Comment: That's not exactly a custom tag. This is recognizeable as a Spring MVC tag.

Comment: @BalusC Which is a custom tag. My point in saying "whatever custom tag that is" is that the OP didn't state the framework, version, etc. and as such is going to get correspondingly generic answers.